# Installing Codeception without local web application

Tags: codeception

Can I install and use Codeception without a web application stored locally?  I tried downloading codecept.phar to its own directory, but when I run "php codecept.phar bootstrap" I get "c??????" in front of my console prompt.  Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.  Longer answer: I needed to upgrade my version of PHP.